# Who discovered the stopping voltage in the photoelectric effect

Tags: specific-reference, photoelectric-effect

It's widely considered that Lenard observed stopping voltage in his study of photoelectric effect: Lenard P., Annalen der Physik, 8, 149-198 (1902). In this work Lenard cites, among others, A.G.Stoletow's papers: A. G. Stoletow, Journ. d. russ. phys. chem. Ges. 21. 1889; Uebersetzung mit Zuegtzen dee Verfassers in Phys. Revue 1. p. 721. 1892.

Does anyone have an English or Russian translation of these papers and and/or more information regarding the discovery of stopping potential in photoelectric effect?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably a better fit to [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to retain this question in view of the findings in Wong D. et al, Eur. J. Phys., 32, 1059-1064 (2011). The latter indicates that stopping potential may not be only of historic significance and if one is to study it now he or she has to start w/ the origins.Unfortunately, they are in German and a translation will be of help in such study.

Comment: @stafusa [tag:specific-reference]s are perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @stafusa how do you vote to migrate to history stack exchange?

Comment: @XcoderX,, What I did was vote to close giving my own reason. You might also flag the post as needing attention from the moderators and explaining the situation. But note that here, as Kyle pointed out, I was mistaken.

Comment: @KyleKanos, thanks for pointing that out. I already retracted my vote.

Comment: Yes, I did not flag this post, but I would like to know how you flagged and give your reason

Answer (score 0):

The Stoletov's article was also issued as a separate edition in 1889, according to https://profilib.net/chtenie/108012/viktor-bolkhovitinov-stoletov-79.php , and this edition (in Russian) can be found at http://books.e-heritage.ru/book/10071380 . I had a quick look at it and did not find anything about stopping potential, but I may have missed something (I do speak Russian, but the article is pretty long, and the terminology could be quite different).